# Java - dom4j prefixing UTF-8 value with Â value

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, dom4j

I am working with an XML Writer (dom4j) and the following UTF-8 Value is being passed in : "Some Text ®"
I.e. the Registration Symbol.

My Character encoding is set to UTF-8, however, when the XML File is generated it appears as follows:

"Some Text Â®"

How can this be amended so that the UTF-8 value appears as is i.e. just the registration symbol.

Example code snippet:

```
FulfilmentFileWriter fulfilmentFileWriter = new FulfilmentFileWriter ();
OutputStream fulfilmentOutput;

fulfilmentFileWriter.setEncoding("UTF-8"); 
fulfilmentOutput = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\Test.xml");                             

fulfilmentFileWriter.open(fulfilmentOutput, "Test");

fulfilmentFileWriter.writeOrder(fulfilmentOrder);

fulfilmentFileWriter.close();
```

Comment: Uhm, this is not very sane to name a class after one already present in the JDK... What does your `FileWriter` class look like?

Comment: I have edited it now to be the real class name, previously I was just using a made up name that just so hapened to be FileWriter.

Comment: Without knowing the code from `ThamesNewFulfilmentFileWriter` we can't help

Comment: Do you need to see the entire class code, or just the methods I am calling?

Comment: When encoded as UTF-8 the registration symbol becomes the two-byte sequence `C2 AE` so the encoding is likely being done correctly. My guess is that the bug is in how you are decoding/viewing the resultant data - interpreting the data as [windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) instead of UTF-8.

Comment: I agree. The weird thing is when I run this unit test on Windows and open the file in notepad++ with encoding set to UTF-8, it appears fine and as expected. However, when I transfer the unmodified file across to a sun solaris box then the Â symbol appears. This is an issue we are getting in production. Could it be platform related?

Comment: Does the generated XML header specify a wrong encoding like: `<?xml encoding="Cp1252"?>`?

Comment: No it specifies the correct encoding: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Answer (score 0):

Ok Problem now solved. It was to do with my Putty terminal not displaying the file in the encoding I was expecting (UTF-8). In order to fix this I did the following:

Setting up Putty to correctly display UTF-8 characters:

- Right click Putty
- Click 'Change Settings'
- Navigate to Window > Translation
- Select 'UTF-8' from the drop down menu.
- Click 'Apply' to save the changes.

Thanks.